# To prove that a polynomial is divisible by another polynomial .

Tags: complex-numbers

$x^{4p}$+$x^{(4q+1)}+x^{(4r+2)}+x^{(4s+ 3)} $is divisible by x^3+x^2+x+1, where ,q ,r ,s belongs to Natural numbers.

So , I did is this :

$x^3+x^2+x+1$ = $(x^2+1)(x+1)$ , So , x = +1 and -1.

Then , put in f(1) and f(-1). But I am not able to solve it further after this step.

Comment: The web is full of solutions, e.g. [here](https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/show-that-the-polynomial-x4px4q1x4r2x4s3-is-divisible-by-x3x2x1-where-pqrsin-n/), or [here](https://doubtnut.com/question-answer/show-that-the-polynomial-x4p-x4q-1-x4r-2-x4s-3-is-divisible-by-x3-x2-x-1-w-h-e-r-ep-q-r-s-in-ndot-29353), or [here](https://www.askiitians.com/forums/Algebra/22/23690/complex-number.htm) etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zeros of the polynomial $(x^2+1)(x+1)$ are $-1,\pm i$. (I hope you are acquainted with $i=\sqrt{-1}.$) Show that $f(x) = x^{4p} + x^{4q+1} + x^{4r+2} + x^{4s+3}$ satisfies $$f(-1)=f(i) = f(-i) = 0.$$ Hence conclude (e.g., by factor theorem) that the polynomial (not the number itself) $(x+1)(x^2+1)$ divides the polynomial $f(x).$